# Conditional display based on devise authentication status

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using Devise 3.4.0, Rails 4.1.8.

Once the user hits `sessions#new`, puts in their username and password, and clicks the "log in" button, Devise POSTS to `/users/sign_in`. If authentication succeeds, the user gets redirected. However, I need to do something a little differently in the view if authentication fails. Basically, we have two types of accounts: legacy and modern.

Modern accounts are no problem: they come from our Rails system, so we know a bad login is a bad login. They definitely have an account, they're just using the wrong password. I want to display additional help text to them outside of the flash message (which I am also using).

However, we've imported legacy accounts into our system; we just haven't assigned them passwords. If they're trying to log in with a legacy account, I want to display the same flash message, but different help text outside of the flash message.

I'm looking for something like this (if the logic were in the view; stick with me for a minute). See the two conditionals at the end?

```
<div class="login_form">
  <div class="flash">
    <%= render partial: 'layouts/flash_messages', locals: { flash_messages: flash } %>
  </div>

  <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, placeholder: "Email" %>
    <%= f.password_field :password, placeholder: "Password" %>
    <%= f.button "Sign in" %>
  <% end %>

  <% if gave_wrong_password? %>
    <a href="/def456">Reset your password here!</a>
  <% elsif no_account_exists? %>
    <a href="/abc123">Create a new account here!</a>
  <% end %> 
</div>
```

Basically, I need Devise (or Warden) to tell me why something has failed. Is there something available to the Devise controller that I can hook into to get that information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you can do is over right the devise model like this

```
#app/controllers/users/sessions_controller.rb

class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  layout 'users/login'

  before_filter :before_signin, :only => [:create]
  after_filter :after_signin, :only => [:create]

  def new
    self.resource = resource_class.new(sign_in_params)
    clean_up_passwords(resource)
    respond_with(resource, serialize_options(resource))
  end

  def create
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    #set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_flashing_format?
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    yield resource if block_given?
    if session[:user_return_to]
      respond_with resource, :location => session[:user_return_to]
    else
      respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    end
  end

  private
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    users_root_path
  end

  def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    new_user_session_path
  end

  def before_signin
    # do something
  end

  def after_signin
    # do something
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! Almost there: this gives me a way check if a user exists or is a legacy user (I can do a query in `before_signin` and set an instance variable that I can use in my view) but how can I tell if an authentication attempt has failed because of an incorrect password?

Comment: I think I've figured out a way around it by checking a couple of different states rather than fighting with Warden. This answer got me started so I will accept it. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks I am.glad that this pointed you in. The right direction